# UITextView copy text from attributedText cause app crash

Tags: ios, uitextview

I'm using an UITextView with a Lorem Ipsum text in it. I'm just highlight some of the text with bold and different kind of font, so I'm using `attributedText` property.

**Problem**

So, I'm using `attributedText` and on tap in the textView a popup up appears to select text. When I press copy button the app totally crashes without any crash report or exception.

In this picture I had already pressed the copy button, and the app is crashed.

[image]

Comment: You can enable the exception breakpoints and maybe you can see the line which is causing the crash. If you can't solve it afterwards, maybe you can edit the question and add the line causing the crash.

Comment: I have already added the exception handler (All Exceptions) but its not catching anything at all.